# call JS function from select box

Tags: javascript, php

I am using MVC pattern for building a PHP movie web. 
in View class, I print out the select box that contain an array.

```
print "
        <div>
            <div class='top-nav'>
                <label for='actor'>Actor:</label>
                <select name='actor' id='id-actor' onchange='movieFilterChanged();'>
                    <option value='all'> Select All </option>
    ";            
                    foreach($actors as $actor){
                        print "
                            <option value='".$actor['actor_id']."'> ".$actor['actor_name']." </option>
                        ";
                    }                          
    print "                
                </select>
            </div>
    ";
```

The JS function `movieFilterChanged()` will be triggered when value was selected. I wrote the simple JS function :

```
function movieFilterChanged(){
    var actor = document.getElementById('id_actor').value;
    if (actor != 'all')
        alert("actor");
}
```

But this JS function is not triggered.

Comment: `id_actor` != `id-actor`

Comment: as he suggested gogaz change
`<select name='actor' id='id-actor' onchange='movieFilterChanged();'>` to `<select name='actor' id='id_actor' onchange='movieFilterChanged();'>` or change in your function `var actor = document.getElementById('id_actor').value;` to `var actor = document.getElementById('id-actor').value;`

Comment: unbelievable. it's work.

Comment: because they are considered two different ids

Comment: Are you sure the methode is not triggerd. Check with google chrome debugging tool or just place the alert("actor"); inside the function. As @gogaz said your getElementById selector is wrong. But the function should be called. Anyway pleace also verify that your function is placed after the html...

Answer (score 1):

Firts change the **id** from your **select**:

```
id='id_actor'
```

Try use alert without *quotation marks*:

```
alert(actor);
```

And you can add a else in your if, like this:

```
else {
 alert(actor);
}
```

OR use:

```
console.log(actor);
```

> You will see the value of the actor and you will notice that you are
>   using a different id

Comment: this is not the answer to the question

Comment: Yeah that would not really work because of the fact that the var actor is always undefined because the selector is wrong. And as @Leo mentioned it does not answer the question.

Comment: I do not know who put you on the positive vote, but it is wrong

Comment: the solution is written in the comments above for several minutes, rather copy it

Comment: In my first answer, I tried to help debugge your own code and that he would find the problem of the different id, already edit and complement the answer, in the same way thank you for your concern @Leo ;)

Comment: if he wants to print "actor" as a string and not as a variable, he is free to do it .. it is not an error. the mistake was only the wrong id. ;) @ArmandoMariscal

Comment: That's right, he's free to do it, it was just a suggestion, there's no problem. ;)

Comment: In addition, it is clear that he needs to get the identification number of the actor and not just show a string.